# How to use inside ajax function json value to jsp page?

Tags: json, ajax, jsp

How to generate the table on that json value. inside the ajax function data is print in console and also in jsp but out side of it value is undefined what is the mistake?

```
<head>
<title>Spring MVC Ajax Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doAjax() {
    var samp;
    $.ajax({
        url : '/RoomController/ViewMember',
        type : 'GET',
        success : function(data) {
            samp=data;
            console.log(samp[0].memberName);
            $('#json').html(samp[3].memberName);
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("memberList").value=samp;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="demo" onclick="doAjax()" title="Button">Get the
    time!</button>
<div id="time">
    <label id="json"></label>
    <input type="hidden" id="memberList" name="memberList">
    <table>
        <c:forEach items="${memberList}" var="firstname">
            <tr>
                <td>${firstname.memberName}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>

    </table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Note : This uses JQuery

Javascript :

```
var myList = [{"name" : "abc", "age" : 50},
          {"age" : "25", "hobby" : "swimming"},
          {"name" : "xyz", "hobby" : "programming"}];

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList.
function buildHtmlTable(selector) {
    var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector);

for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
    var row$ = $('<tr/>');
    for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
        var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];

        if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }

        row$.append($('<td/>').html(cellValue));
    }
    $(selector).append(row$);
}
}

// Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
// Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
// all records

function addAllColumnHeaders(myList, selector)

{
    var columnSet = [];
var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
    var rowHash = myList[i];
    for (var key in rowHash) {
        if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
            columnSet.push(key);
            headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
        }
    }
}
$(selector).append(headerTr$);

return columnSet;
}​
```

HTML :

```
<body onLoad="buildHtmlTable('#excelDataTable')">
<table id="excelDataTable" border="1">
  </table>
</body>​
```

To call the table, try

```
table.on('xhr', function() {
  var ajaxJson = table.ajax.json();
  alert(ajaxJson.data.length + ' row(s) were loaded');
});
```

Change it according to your code.

Comment: That's ok but how to get the 'samp' value out side of ajax  function. simply  i put ' console.log(samp[0].memberName);' out side of ajax means it is undefined.